# counting values per subject

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to add a new column to a dataset called `COUNT`. My dataset has a variables subject, `tox1` , `tox2`, `tox3` (character variables) with  different values. A subject can appear multiple times in my dataset, I want to count the occurrence of `'ADR'` per subject. What I want to do is create a new variable called `COUNT` that counts how many times a subject has a specific value ie `'ADR'` for `tox1`, `tox2` and `tox3`; when a SUBJECT does not have an observation for that specific value, I want `COUNT` to have a result of zero.

Here's an example of the dataset I would like (in this example, I want to count every instance of `"ADR"` per `SUBJECT` as `COUNT`).

```
 INPUT subject $ tox1 $ tox2 $ tox3 $;
 datalines;
1   ADR c s
1   ADR d f
1   s ADR f
1   a w e 
2   d f g
3   e d ADR 
3   k ADR f
4   N ADR ADR
4   Q ADR d
4   ADR d f
4   r v h 
4   ADR f g
5   g f d
5   r t u
5   g h j   
;
```

[THIS IS INPUT DATASET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnLPm.png)

```
SUBJECT TOX1 TOX2 TOX3 COUNT
1   ADR c s    3
1   ADR d f    3
1   s ADR f    3
1   a w e      3
2   d f g      0 
3   e d ADR    2
3   k ADR f    2 
4   N ADR ADR  5
4   Q ADR d    5
4   ADR d f    5
4   r v h      5
4   ADR f g    5
5   g f d      0
5   r t u      0
5   g h j      0
```

[THIS IS THE REQUIRED OUTPUT FOR COUNT VARIABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdrlP.png)

Comment: You were lucky enough to get answer.  Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.  Show some effort in what you tried or investigated and what errors you encountered.  Nicely put, Can you do my work is not a question.

Comment: man....I tried to code my program but that did not worked. I m new to stackoverflow and I was not aware about the interface .I was not trying to write the code here  but just showing the program .Also i was trying to get the count on different conditions. Please dont think that  I wasted Your valuable time.I respect your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data step approach

```
data have;
INPUT subject $ tox1 $ tox2 $ tox3 $; 
datalines; 
1 ADR c   s   
1 ADR d   f   
1 s   ADR f   
1 a   w   e   
2 d   f   g   
3 e   d   ADR 
3 k   ADR f   
4 N   ADR ADR 
4 Q   ADR d   
4 ADR d   f   
4 r   v   h   
4 ADR f   g   
5 g   f   d   
5 r   t   u   
5 g   h   j   
;

data want (drop = i);
   count = 0;
   do _N_ = 1 by 1 until (last.subject);
      set have;
      by subject;
      array tox {3};
      do i = 1 to dim(tox);
         if tox [i] = 'ADR' then count = sum(count, 1);
      end;
   end;
   do _N_ = 1 to _N_;
      set have;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Result:

```
count subject tox1 tox2 tox3 
3     1       ADR  c    s 
3     1       ADR  d    f 
3     1       s    ADR  f 
3     1       a    w    e 
0     2       d    f    g 
2     3       e    d    ADR 
2     3       k    ADR  f 
5     4       N    ADR  ADR 
5     4       Q    ADR  d 
5     4       ADR  d    f 
5     4       r    v    h 
5     4       ADR  f    g 
0     5       g    f    d 
0     5       r    t    u 
0     5       g    h    j
```

Comment: Thanks Draycut.That was really Helpful.